# Unable to load index.html from subdirectories using express in electron

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I have a simple express server running inside electron. I can get to `index.html` in my `public` directory, but trying to load `public/sub/index.html` results in `Cannot GET /sub/index.html`.

What am I missing here?

Folder structure:

```
app-root
  - public
    |
     - sub
    | |
    |  - index.html // doesn't work
     - index.html // works
```

Code:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')

const exp = express()

exp.set('/', __dirname + '/public')
exp.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

exp.listen(80)

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  let window = new BrowserWindow({show: true})
  window.loadURL('http://localhost/sub/index.html')
  window.on('closed', () => {
    app.quit()
  })
})
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I only deviated from your code by using a different port number.

Comment: Thanks for testing.. I will try a different port number and see if that changes things